# Syntax Error - Unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm responding to a Controller Action via Javascript. I want to render a partial. depending on if the shopping cart is empty or already has items on it, I have different Selectors to append the partial to.

The General markup is the following:

```
<div id="expresscart">
  <ul id="expresslist">
    <li class="expressitem">..</li>
    <li class="expressitem">..</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason, I have no issue appending the li after another 'li.expressitem'.

But as soon, as I want to insert the first *li* into the *ul* I'm getting following error:

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'

The JS thats responding to the action is the following:

```
$('.linktocart a').html('<%= escape_javascript link_to_cart %>');
<% if current_order.empty? %>
  $("#expresslist").append("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'spree/line_items/express', :locals => {:line_item => @line_item} %>");
<% else %>
  $(".expressitem:last").after("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'spree/line_items/express', :locals => {:line_item => @line_item} %>");
<% end %>
```

The Partial to be rendered is the following:

```
%li.expressitem{"data-expresslineid" => line_item.id}
  %div.expressimage
    - if line_item.variant.images.any?
      %figure
        = image_tag line_item.variant.images.last.attachment.url(:sideline)
  .expressdescription
    %h1
      = line_item.variant.product.name
      %span.expressprice
        = line_item.money
    %p.expressitemdesc.clearfix
      = line_item.item_options
    - if line_item.subscription_line
      %p.expressautoship
        = t(:autoship_every, :month => pluralize(line_item.subscription.interval, 'month'))

  %div.expressitemoptions
    %ul.inline
      %li.expressremove
        = link_to(t(:remove), '#')
```

I'm just wondering, what am I missing here?

Comment: What does the final rendered JS look like? Can you post it?

Comment: Have a look at the generated output and you might find the problem.

Comment: This looks like a RoR syntax error, not a javascript one.

Comment: I know lots of people do it, but you shouldn't put a `div` inside of a `li` however that is not your real problem. are you getting that error in a javascript console, or in your dev server log?

Comment: It seems, the error is gone after removing a trailing space in the JS. However, the item still does not appear in the list.

Comment: Why would people debug JavaScript by looking at serverside code?